# JLabel positions not working in Java

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm trying to make positions for my labels i have created and added to a panel. 
Right now, I have some text, and an icon. I want to change to position for the icon to be in the bottom.

My code:

```
    frame = new JFrame(); // Create a new frame
    frame.setVisible(true); // Makes it visible     
    frame.setSize(900, 500); // Sets size         
    frame.setTitle(""); // Sets title
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Sets the window on the center of the screen   

    //Create temperature panel      
    temp_panel = new JPanel(); // Creates new JPanel
    temp_panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#f1c40f")); // Sets color

    //Create temperature label
    temp_label = new JLabel("Temperature");
    label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(temp_icon));

    //Add label to temperature panel
    temp_panel.add(temp_label);
    temp_panel.add(label1);

    // Creates the main panel for all panels
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    panel.add(temp_panel);

    // Add panel to frame
    frame.add(panel);
```

My goal is to make multiple labels on a panel, and control where they are going to be placed, like this example:

```
--------------
|    TEXT    |            
|            |
|            |
|    Text    |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|    Icon    |
--------------
```

Have tried thing like:

```
temp_label = new JLabel("Temperature", BorderLayout.END.PAGE);
```

This dont seem to help, because my labels are just positioned in the top.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

```
temp_label = new JLabel("Temperature", BorderLayout.END.PAGE);
```

since if you look at the JLabel API, you'll not find a constructor that takes a BorderLayout constant, nor would it make sense even if it were legal. We would sometimes call code like the above -- throwing poop at the wall and seeing what sticks. This heuristic rarely works in programming. You will want to use the Java API resource to avoid making up things like this.

As to your problem, you're adding your JLabel to a JPanel that uses a default FlowLayout. If you want its contents to stack as in your image, give that JPanel a *different* layout. Here a BoxLayout that uses the PAGE_AXIS sounds about right.

Please check out the [layout manager tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more on this and other layouts.

Comment: So i have to give my temp_panel a new layout? like this:
temp_panel = new JPanel(new something??());

Comment: @Mikkel: better for you to try it and see what happens.